# Traversing Pages with since_id and max_id

Tags: c#, twitter

I am currently migrating code over to Twitters 1.1. Previously I was doing a series of GET requests for search/tweets based traversing pages using the page parameter. However with 1.1 you have to use since_id and max_id. While I understand the idea behind the two params I am wondering what is the preferred way of getting say 500 tweets (or N) tweets using these param options.

Currently I am doing a get request with a blank since_id param, I then set this param to the last str_id of the tweets I got back. So for my next iteration of get requests I have a since_id equal to the last id of the last tweet iv got. Really not sure if im doing it right.

Anyone know a good solution to traversing pages using these two params?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you work up to newer (more recent tweets) from since_id. You work back to older tweets from max_id. You can use the parameter count to size the timeline. The returned count may constrained by rate limits. Hope that helps!

Refer:
See this document for working with timelines here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines
Or try building your query using the Twitter dev console here: https://dev.twitter.com/console